Can I return while inside a Win32 CriticalSection?
I have a Win32 API question about critical sections.
Is it OK to return when in a critical section? Or once you enter the section do you have to fall through and leave the section? Here's some sample code:
//option one
bool doSomething() {

    EnterCriticalSection(&section);
    
    if(something)
        return true;        

    return false; 

    LeaveCriticalSection(&section);
}

//option two
bool doSomething() {

    bool flag = false;

    EnterCriticalSection(&section);
    
    if(something)
        flag = true; 

    LeaveCriticalSection(&section);

    return flag;
}


I hope I can go with option one and return from inside the section and that will release any locks.

Of course no. You ( your code ) must release  critical section

OT: Option 1 is wrong anyway, because it doesn't return anything if something is false.

@Jabberwocky fixed

@user1337497 your "fix" made it worse. The return false; statement must be after LeaveCriticalSection(&section);

@Jabberwocky its not supposed to be fixed.. its showing 2 examples of returning a value... first returning in the section and second returning outside the section.

@user1337497 then you should remove LeaveCriticalSection(&section); which isn't going to be called anyway. If you submit examples, they should at least make some sense.

@Jabberwocky I need the examples as is to help clarify my question... Can I return while inside a Win32 CriticalSection? Everybody else gets it except you.

Keep in mind that the Win32 API is written for C. Nothing happens automatically, everything is explicit. So, if you use the API directly, as your example is doing, then you must leave the CS explicitly, otherwise you risk deadlocking other threads that want to enter the CS.
Every successful call to (Try)EnterCriticalSection() MUST have a corresponding call to LeaveCriticalSection(). This is stated in the documentation:

A thread uses the EnterCriticalSection or TryEnterCriticalSection function to request ownership of a critical section. It uses the LeaveCriticalSection function to release ownership of a critical section...
... To release its ownership, the thread must call LeaveCriticalSection one time for each time that it entered the critical section...

If you are using a language like C++ that supports OOP programming, and you want to leave the CS automatically when going out of scope, then you need an RAII-style wrapper whose constructor enters the CS and destructor leaves the CS.

I read that documentation but wanted to make sure. This legacy code is using the second approach. It makes for a few more lines of code to be able to fall through the section which I wanted to avoid but thanks for the idea of how one could place the enter and leave in their design.

@user1337497 There is no need to read the documentation here. Here you need to think a little. no one can call LeaveCriticalSection for you. so your code must do this one way or another or the section will be occupied by the current thread forever

As suggested in the previous answer, if you're using C++ you can do something like this :
class CriticalSection
{
  LPCRITICAL_SECTION mysection;
public:
  CriticalSection(LPCRITICAL_SECTION section) : mysection(section)
  {
    EnterCriticalSection(&mysection);
  };

  ~CriticalSection()
  {
    LeaveCriticalSection(&mysection);
  };
};


//option one
bool doSomething() {
  CriticalSection cr(section);
  ...
  if (something)
    return true;
  ...
  return false;
}

Disclaimer:

this is untested code, it may contain bugs


The obvious bug is that you don't actually initialize the section inside the CriticalSection class.
